# Autorest client generation multiple references of newtonsoft

Tags: autorest

Currently i am trying to build an autogenerating client on every time i release a new api.

I've got this running i can create the project and generate files from autorest.exe and everything works fine on my machine.

However when i try to replicate the same process on the buildserver i build my sln, and once i pack i get this error:

`[pack] 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime' already has a dependency defined for 'Newtonsoft.Json'.`

I have added this to my csproj file to pick up on the generated files, and this works fine on my local machine.

```
<Compile Include="Generated\*.cs" />
<Compile Include="Generated\Models\*.cs" />
```

I also tried including referenced projects on the build server like so

```
-IncludeReferencedProjects
```

After a couple of days im kind of stuck here, i have been having trouble finding docs on how to actually build the autorest generated client code, if anyone knows of some please share :)

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was to update nuget on teamcity from 3.2.0 to 3.4.3 then the solution would build and run the files, i am still not sure what changed since this couldnt build, but somehow with 3.2.0 i had 2 references to newtonsoft within Microsoft.rest.clientruntime, when i updated it went away.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of searching, the answer was to run 'nuget update -self' on the failing copy of nuget.exe.